# NUnit Server Web interface

Tags: nunit

I'm searching for a kind of NUnit server with web interface, where I can start my NUnit test while on vacation or on the road... Is there any setup that can realise my idea or do I need to develop something?

All I found so far was set up NUnit on multiple machines, as I searched for remote control or web interface.

Kind regards

bnz

Answer (score 1):

A continuous integration tool such as [JetBrains TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) can provide automated NUnit testing as part of a new build. It is possible to manually start new builds via *TeamCity's* web interface, and the build/test results are also easily retrievable via the web.

*TeamCity* is a commercial product, but if your project qualifies as an open-source project you can apply for a [free](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/buy/index.jsp) *TeamCity* license.

**UPDATE** Listing a few alternative continuous integration servers that I have no personal experience of.

There is also [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), an open-source continuous integration server primarily for Java development but that comes with plug-ins for both MSBuild and NUnit, as well as a large number of versioning control software plug-ins.

[CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/), open-source, also primarily aimed at Java development. Also available as a .NET implementation called [CruiseControl.NET](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/).

A comprehensive list of different continuous integration software can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_continuous_integration_software).

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look for alternatives. Do you know any other open-source solution?